# script to record terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

`script` is a great tool to record all activities in terminal(http://linuxers.org/article/script-command-line-tool-recordsave-your-terminal-activity). The builtin `script` executable on Mac is not able to record the timing of the typescript. I am trying to compile the package util-linux (https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux, which contains linux version `script`) but without success:

```
$ make
make  all-recursive
Making all in po
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-strutils.lo
In file included from lib/strutils.c:16:
./include/strutils.h:77: error: conflicting types for 'strmode'
/usr/include/string.h:168: error: previous declaration of 'strmode' was here
lib/strutils.c:351: error: conflicting types for 'strmode'
/usr/include/string.h:168: error: previous declaration of 'strmode' was here
lib/strutils.c: In function 'size_to_human_string':
lib/strutils.c:442: warning: format '%jd' expects type 'intmax_t', but argument 8 has type 'uint64_t'
make[2]: *** [lib/libcommon_la-strutils.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there any compiled excutable out there for Mac?

Answer (score 10):

The `script`version on OS X has the `-r` option, which will record all input, output and timings in a single file. it can be replayed using the `-p` option.

---

Instructions:

**START:**

`$ script -r`

Start typing commands...

**STOP:**

`$ exit`

**REPLAY:**

`$ script -p typescript`

Answer (score 7):

`ttyrec` includes a fix for the timing issue and, for all intents and purposes, serves the same function (described as a derivative of `script` in its manpage). It's available via brew (`brew install ttyrec`) or MacPorts (`sudo port install ttyrec`).

- [ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/): Official website
- [shelr.tv](http://shelr.tv/): YouTube for terminal recordings
- [ttygif](https://github.com/icholy/ttygif): Converts terminal recordings to animated GIFs

Comment: OSX High Sierra: `Error: Port ttyrec not found` and the brew version fails `Out of pty's` :(

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else stumbles here trying to figure out how to replay scripts on MacOS that were recorded with the util-linux version of `script`, you might find this useful:

https://bitbucket.org/rewbs/docker-scriptreplay

It's just a really simple Alpine Linux based Docker image that enables you to run `scriptreplay` on MacOS (via Docker). I found this useful to ensure a wide audience of Mac users could replay scripts recorded on Linux servers using standard tools. Hope someone else finds this useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to compile the package util-linux (https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux, which contains linux version script) but without success:

The error message from the compiler on the 'incompatible types' is the clue to why it failed. There's a conflict between the declarations in the system header files resident on OS X (BSD-based) and those in the include files from `util-linux`(GNU/Linux based).